# Most efficiency handling in Emgu CV

Tags: c#, video-capture, emgucv

I write an application that scan video files twice:

Firstly, it extracts frames from 4 video files by `Capture.QueryFrame()`, merge them to single frames (i.e. all 4 frames from different videos, merged to single frame), and display the result to the user.
Secondly, it needs to extract the frames and merge them again, and then to process the result.

I think about two options to do that:

1. To extract the frames, merge them and save the result to new temporary video file by `VideoWriter`, and in the second time to extract only one frame from the temporary file.
2. To extract the frames from the source video files twice.

Which way is more effectively? i.e. Which operation is more quickly- to extract frames (like in the second way) or to save frames to new video file (as the first way)?
Or maybe there is other way?